# como hago para que los FloatingActionButton me queden en paralelo y no uno encima del otro

Tags: flutter, dart

Este es el bloque de mi contador.
Me gustaría que como se ve en la imagen me quedaran en paralelo y no una encima de la otra.

```
    container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 30, 0),
          child: FloatingActionButton( //Este es uno de los FloatingActionButtons
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: _incrementCount,
          )),

    Text('${atermino}'), //Aca  me muestra el contador 

    Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 30, 0),
          child: FloatingActionButton( //Este es el  segundo FloatingActionButton
            child: Icon(Icons.remove),
            onPressed: _decrementCount,
          )),
```

[Acá esta la imagen de como me queda actualmente](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4skU.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los metes en un `Row`:

```
   Row(
      children:[
        Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 30, 0),
              child: FloatingActionButton( //Este es uno de los FloatingActionButtons
                child: Icon(Icons.add),
                onPressed: _incrementCount,
              )),
    
        Text('${atermino}'), //Aca  me muestra el contador 
    
        Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 30, 0),
              child: FloatingActionButton( //Este es el  segundo FloatingActionButton
                child: Icon(Icons.remove),
                onPressed: _decrementCount,
              )),
      ]
    )
```